# Would styleURL in an Angular component be faster or more efficient than having a compiled and transpiled app.css built from all the scss files?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, gruntjs

I'm not sure I'm understanding the purpose of `styleURLS` in Angular.

All my scss files compile to one large css file, and the entire app points to that css file. As such, the html generated with the angular components will look at that to get the right styles for the right classes.

However, I can also provide styleURLs property to the component directly, in which case the component points to the scss files.

It would seem that this *should* be more efficient, but I have no knowledge that it is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure about efficiency, but it's mainly for modularity.

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

> Angular can bundle component styles with components, enabling a more modular design than regular stylesheets

> The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component

This will give you the following benefits

> - You can use the CSS class names and selectors that make the most sense in the context of each component.
> - Class names and selectors are local to the component and don't collide with classes and selectors used elsewhere in the application.
> - Changes to styles elsewhere in the application don't affect the component's styles.
> - You can co-locate the CSS code of each component with the TypeScript and HTML code of the component, which leads to a neat and tidy project structure.
> - You can change or remove component CSS code without searching through the whole application to find where else the code is used.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know about efficiency, but the styleUrls per component is one of the basic principles Angular is trying to impose with its design patterns, which is modularity. That's why we have Components, Directives, Pipes, Modules, Services etc.

Also, try reading into View Encapsulation in Angular and understand how that works in combination with your stylesheets, and maybe this answers your question.

If it doesn't, it's very likely I didn't fully understand what you're wondering.
Good luck!